# Numbering definitions, propositions etc. based on section, subsection?

Tags: newtheorem

I would like to organise my text so that definitions, propositions, examples etc in subsection x.y are numbered x.y.1, x.y.2, x.y.3, ... independently of whether they are definitions or theorems or whatever, like this:

```
Section 1
Subsection 1.1
Definition 1.1.1
Lemma 1.1.2
Theorem 1.1.3
Corollary 1.1.4
Example 1.1.5
Subsection 1.2
Definition 1.2.1
Lemma 1.2.2
...
Section 2
Subsection 2.1
Definition 2.1.1
...
```

In other words, where the 'counter' is the same for definitions, theorems etc. and ONLY depends on what section/subsection it is in. I have tried using `\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]` etc. and it seems to completely ignore which subsection it is in. How do I remedy this?

Comment: You need `[subsection]`, not `[section]`

Comment: Use `\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[subsection]`, not `section` if you want the counter to be reset at each new subsection.

Comment: It seems to change based on the subsection now, but the definitions, propositions etc. all seem to count separately e.g. Def 1.1.1, Prop 1.1.1, Def 1.1.2, Example 1.1.1... How do I combine the counters so they work together?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the parent counter with `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]`, you can set all the other theorem types to use `theorem` as a sibling counter with e.g. `\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{definition}
text
\end{definition}
\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
text
\end{theorem}
\begin{corollary}
text
\end{corollary}
\begin{example}
text
\end{example}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\begin{definition}
text
\end{definition}
\begin{lemma}
text
\end{lemma}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection}

\begin{definition}
text
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image: theorems]